# search engine with pagination: issue on page 1

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Please help me, i tried to create search engine with pagination, everything seems fine except when i click back to page1's link, it pull out data from mysql orderly not from my inputted query, but this happen only on my page one.when i click  i need really help on this!!!

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
mysql_query("Use igstore");
$pagesquery = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('creatorid') FROM `creator`");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pagesquery, 0)/$perpage);
$page = (isset($_GET['page']))?(int)$_GET['page']:1;
$start = ($page-1)*$perpage;

//to filter from inputted data from textbox and combobox
if($value == null&&$genre == null&&$star == null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `creator` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$find%' OR `creatorid` LIKE '$item' LIMIT $start, $perpage";}
else if($value != null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `creator` WHERE `aprice` = '$value' OR `creatorid` LIKE '$item' LIMIT $start, $perpage";}
else if($genre != null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `creator` WHERE `type` = '$genre' OR `creatorid` LIKE '$item' LIMIT $start, $perpage";}
else if($star != null){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `creator` WHERE `popular` = '$star' OR `creatorid` LIKE '$item' LIMIT $start, $perpage";}
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($_GET = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $head = $_GET['title'];
      $def = $_GET['description'];
      $pric = $_GET['aprice'];
      $blob = $_GET['img1'];
     echo"<html>";
    echo'<table height="180" width="1300">';
     echo"<tr>";
         echo'<th align="center">';
          echo'<div class="ab">';
     echo'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($blob).'"/ width="150px" height="150px">';
              echo'</div>';
              echo'</th>';
         echo'<th align="left">';
         echo'<div class="container">';
         echo"<a href='#'><h3>$head</h3></a>";
         echo"<textarea style='resize: none;border: none' rows='5' cols='60' readonly>$def</textarea><br>";
         echo"<label class='control-label col-sm-2'><h5>ราคา: $pric</h5></label><br><br>";
         echo"</div>";
         echo'</th>'; 
         echo"</tr>";
         echo'</table>';
         echo'<hr width="100%">';
         echo"</html>"; 
           }
//this is for showing page number
         $prev = $page - 1;
         $next = $page + 1;
         echo "<a href='result.php?page=$prev' style='display: inline-block';>Prev</a>";
         for($index=1;$index<=$pages;$index++){
        echo ($page == $index)?'<b><a href="?page='.$index.'" style="display: inline-block"; >'.$index.'</a> </b>':'<a href="?page='.$index.'" style="display: inline-block"; >'.$index.'</a>';
        }
         echo "<a href='result.php?page=$next' style='display: inline-block';>Next</a>";

?>
```

Comment: Where did you declare your `$perpage` variable? And your `$pagesquery` should also have the same condition (except of course for the `LIMIT`) with the query below.

Comment: I declare on top but it might be accidentally erased when i posted, for pagequery, i used select count to provide total record i have, but do you have any idea about my first page?